# Mail going missing with Spamassassin, Postfix and Dovecot

Tags: centos, postfix, spamassassin, amavis

I am setting up a new Centos8 server with Spamassassin, Postfix and Dovecot, ClamAV and Amavis.

All was going well until I added a third domain, the first two worked fine for receiving and sending e-mails. Now I have the very odd problem of mail not getting through to the 3rd domain. So my test is as follows:

- Compose mail from test domain to an address @ domain 3
- Copy in addresses @ domain 1 & 2
- Send mail from Server A (test domain) to    Server B (domain 1-3)

The test mail arrives in the inbox of domain 1 & 2 but nothing arrived in the inbox of domain 3.

There is no mention of mail going to domain 3 in `maillog` on Server B or being blocked, but there is a record of the message going to domain 1 & 2.

If I send a message to  domain 3 and don't CC the other domains nothing appears in the maillog.

The spamdlog does show something regarding SPF:

```
Tue Mar 24 17:26:47 2020 [15085] info: spamd: connection from ::1 [::1]:57550 to port 783, fd 5
Tue Mar 24 17:26:47 2020 [15085] info: spamd: processing message <FA6DB725-EAFB-41A1-9121-B0C1EAE7ED9E@domain3.net> for spamd:1003
Tue Mar 24 17:26:47 2020 [15085] info: spamd: clean message (0.0/5.0) for spamd:1003 in 0.6 seconds, 4065 bytes.
Tue Mar 24 17:26:47 2020 [15085] info: spamd: result: . 0 - HTML_MESSAGE,SPF_HELO_NONE scantime=0.6,size=4065,user=spamd,uid=1003,required_score=5.0,rhost=::1,raddr=::1,rport=57550,mid=<FA6DB725-EAFB-41A1-9121-B0C1EAE7ED9E@domain3.net>,autolearn=ham autolearn_force=no
Tue Mar 24 17:26:47 2020 [15079] info: prefork: child states: II
```

So you would assume SPF_HELO_NONE means spamassasin is blocking the message because of a bad SPF record.

Whatever the problem is, how can the message arrive for domain 1 & 2 but not domain 3? Why wouldn't spamassassin be blocking it for all the mailboxes?

I have no user or domain specific settings in the whole system configuration for e-mail other than the Postfix virtual mail boxes and DKIM records in Amavis. And these were all created the same way.